# Visual pattern in IQ test

Tags: pattern-recognition

I recently took an IQ test with 50 questions of visual standard, 42 of which I got right. However, these are the 8 that I was unable to resolve. What do these pictures have in common?
[image]

Comment: In other words, "What do these 'What do these pictures have in common?' pictures have in common?"

Comment: A pattern that the guys who do these tests like to use is the XOR, i.e. having the third picture include exactly the things that appear in exactly one of the first two. I started scoring higher when I first realized there were some. That does not work for all these, though, and I don't think they are supposed to use all the same idea.

Comment: For the fourth one, I'd say $\backslash$ is rotation by $45^\circ$ or so, $/$ is shrinking, and $\times$ is both.